# Disable Auto Replace Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to save the following code:

[image]

But after saving Visual Studio is replacing **this.modalHelpContent['offsetHeight']** by **this.modalHelpContent.offsetHeight** and sets it with an error:

[image]

I am trying to look for where I can remove this autocomplete, but I can't find it.

Btw, the declaration of that variable is " @Input() modalHelpContent: ElementRef;"

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off "Format On Save" in your settings either through the GUI or JSON:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```